# Subversion NoClassFoundDefError

Tags: java, svn, netbeans-6.9

While using subversion several files where placed into 1 package.
Every thing was working perfectly at this point.

Afterwards somebody replaced that package with 5 other ones and divided all the files amongst them.

And now after "updating" the proper files do appear. With the name of the 1 package gone.

But now i keep getting the error:“java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError/**first package name**/Main

Where the first package stands for the package that has long been deleted.
For the person who changed this, the program just works fine.

I can only get to compile the program when i delete every package again and replace all of it with 1 package like it was at the start...

Pretty much tried everything, re-install, clean & build, etc...

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for files in your project directory containing the old package name. Looks like some project metadata that's not under version control wasn't updated. Then either find and fix it in Netbeans or close Netbeans and edit the files directly (backup first, of course).